# Why does my forked process's parent pid differ from the parent's own pid?

Tags: c, fork, pid, unistd.h

I'm trying to understand how some of `unistd.h` functions work.
This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
  pid_t pid;
  pid=fork();
  switch(pid) {
  case 0: //child
     printf("case 0:\nchild %d\nparent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
     break;
  default: //parent
     printf("default:\npid(child) %d\nparent %d\n", pid, getpid());
     break;
  }
}
```

I think that the parent pid obtained by the `getppid()` in the `case 0` and the parent pid obtained by the `getpid()` in the `default` case should be the same, but this is the output of my little program:

```
default:
pid(child) 29208
parent 29207

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.001s
Press ENTER to continue.
case 0:
child 29208
parent 1017
```

Why are they different? (29207 in a case and 1017 in the other)

Comment: My guess is this could be because of improper synchronization of the shell in your terminal. Can you make the child and the parent write their outputs to separate files and compare those instead?

Comment: You should probably `wait()` in the parent for the child to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should slow down execution. AS you can see in you terminal child is executed after parent has finished. In this case it becomes an orphan and its PID is reassigned to different process. I do not know whether this works same on Linux, but on my Mac it was reassigned to process 1. So add `sleep()` before <del>each</del> parent's `printf()`.

**EDIT**

I've compiled (compiled with `llvm-gcc`) and run your code before adding sleep:

```
 $  ./test
default:
pid(child) 2688
parent 2687
case 0:
child 2688
parent 1
```

And afterwards:

```
 $  ./test 
default:
pid(child) 2780
parent 2779
case 0:
child 2780
parent 2779
```

**EDIT2**

Since putting `sleep()` in child's PID solves nothing I changed the suggestion as to where it should be placed.

**EDIT3**

Since it is my answer that got accepted not Toby's which is way better, it is worth mentioning that proper synchronization mechanism would be making use of [`wait()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/wait.htm) function.

Comment: From what I understand, orphan processes are inherited by `init`, and it won't have the id 1017. `sleep` might have fixed this. But for different reasons.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya That's what I was told during my classes. I do not know how exactly it works on Linux (and I do not have any VM at hand to test it quickly). I've added some comparison of what I got during execution though.

Comment: @gonczor I checked it on Linux and I get 1 as PPID if I put a `sleep()` in the child for a second. Apart from that, your solution of putting `sleep()` before both the printf's solves nothing. Maybe you can suggest to add sleep just in the parent. So it terminates definitely after the child has terminated.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya My prof said that with recent OS process may not be reparented to PID1 (init) but to a custom init-user, so I think this is the reason why it has PID 1017

Comment: On some recent Linux, a process can be nominated as an adopter for its (direct and indirect) descendants.  This is implemented to support containers (a container's `init` process isn't necessarily PID 1 in the host namespace).  Perhaps something similar exists on your platform?

Comment: @VincenzoCosi Oh great, everyday I learn something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If the parent does not `wait()` for the child, it may exit before the child calls `getppid()`.  If you want the parent to still exist and be the parent, you can ensure this by making it wait:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
    case 0:
        printf("in child: me: %d; parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        break;
    default: //parent
        printf("in parent: child: %d; me %d\n", pid, getpid());
        wait(NULL);
        break;
    }
}
```

(For your convenience, I've also added the headers you forgot to include - that's a sign that you haven't enabled sufficient warnings in your compilation).